# handling .txt real time in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE* test;
    
    test = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
    
    for(int ch = 48; ch<50; ch++) {
        putc(ch, test);
    }
    
    // the problem is here, i can't get anything that was written
    char u = fgetc(test);
    u = fgetc(test);

}
```

Hey everyone, so... i want to create a text file with C, write an string on it, and after that(while the program is still running), access this string. The problem is, apparently C just "print" the data on the .txt when the execution is finished, that way, i can't have access to the content, any ideas?

Comment: You need to `rewind` the file to get it back to the beginning before attempting to read it back.

Comment: never use magic numberes like 48 or 50. No one knows what that means. Use `for(int ch = '0'; ch<'2'; ch++) {` instead

Comment: @phuclv omg man it's just an example, the problem is not there